# Prepending items in a invertible scroll view for a chat application - react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing a chat application that contains a list of messages for a conversation. When prepending messages to the invertible scroll view (using react-native-invertible-scroll-view), it's automatically scrolling to the top.

What is causing it to scroll to the top and how can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Can you share your code and any error messages you may be getting?

Answer (score 0):

If its a chat application you are better off using a Flatlist.

Comment: but I have seen that the same issue is there in Flat list also . 

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25239#issuecomment-521194810